# Can you cast a key from a for in loop as a property from an interface?

Tags: typescript, casting

In trying to set a property on an object where the value is coming from a dynamically generated form, I’m using a for in loop to find a property in the object and set it

```
   FormFeatureArray.forEach((el) => {

     // form handling stuff omitted
      For(const key in myObject){
        If(key === el.feature){
          myObject.key = formInputField.value
            }
           }
       })
```

This of course throws ts(2339) to which I would like to be able cast **key** as a property of **myObject**, but I can’t know which property of the interface  **key** is referring to, so is there a way to cast **key** as a guaranteed property of the interface of **myObject**, or override the warning for that line? Something like this is what I’m looking for

```
myObject.(key as aPropertyOfMyObject) = formInputField.value
```

The interface for myObject would be some like

```
Interface MyObjects {
Name: string
A: number
B: number 
C: number 
}
```

And **key** can be matching any of those properties of myObject, depending on the field of the form being selected, which is at runtime

Comment: `myObject.key` isn't going to match the key, it's using the literal field `key`, did you mean to do `myObject[key]` instead?

Comment: Aren’t they interchangeable ways of accessing properties on objects?

Comment: @user74091, no. Try for yourself in a JS console: `var key = "foo"; var bar = {}; bar.key=1; bar[key]=2; console.log(JSON.stringify(bar)); //{"key":1,"foo":2}`

Comment: no, i am setting a property on *myObject* and using a for-in loop to search for the property that matches *el.feature*. so i am trying to do *myObject.key* but the value of key changes with each iteration of the loop so how do you cast key? it wont compile with that warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want the `key` to be typed as `keyof MyObject` for the behaviour you are looking for, you could do something like this:

```
const objKeys = Object.keys(myObject) as (keyof typeof myObject)[];
for (const key of objKeys) {
    if (key === el.feature) {
        myObject[key] = formInputField.value;
    }
}
```

note that you need to use `myObject[key]`, using `myObject.key` is equivalent to `myObject["key"]` which is probably not what you intend.  Also since you just need to see if `el.feature` is one of the keys you could skip the for loop entirely by doing this:

```
const objKeys = Object.keys(myObject);
if (objKeys.includes(el.feature)) {
    myObject[el.feature as keyof typeof myObject] = formInputField.value;
}
```

Comment: This looks good let me look once I get back to my computer

Comment: so i opened a ts repl and both of our solutions as i gave them worked, i figured out that the type signature of the interface was what was throwing the error. you wouldnt have known because i wrote down the wrong interface definition

Comment: instead of using `keyof typeof myObject` you could use `keyof MyObject` where the version with capital is the type, using `typeof` guarantees you are referring to the correct interface even if you don't know the type.